# In what order does Django (with postgres) return db queries?

Tags: django, postgresql

I had some stuff on my site that was displaying in a different order depending on what was last edited in the db.

I confirmed that in the shell, the order of what was returned for

```
>>>foo.objects.all()
```

was dependent on what was last edited. I know how I can make the objects display in the order I want, but I could not come up with an explanation for why it was pulling them by the last edit. What field in the database is it going by? Is the database simply ordered differently by what was edited?

Comment: From the [postgres docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/queries-order.html): _If sorting is not chosen, the rows will be returned in an unspecified order. The actual order in that case will depend on the scan and join plan types and the order on disk, but it must not be relied on._

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to set a default ordering, use the [`ordering` meta field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/options/#ordering)

```
class Foo(models.Model):
  # ...
  class Meta:
    ordering = ['some_field', '-another_field']
```

If you do not specify this, the ordering is dependent on the underlying storage system. Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7164126/766952) answer and the [comment by solarissmoke](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32901154/in-what-order-does-django-with-postgres-return-db-queries/32901505#comment53630889_32901154) on your question.

You can later override this using the [`order_by`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.order_by) method of a queryset if needed.