# django templates help,upside down

Tags: python, html, django

I am trying to build my blog using Django 1.8 however I do not know how can I order the blogs. See the image[image]

I want to display the 'earliest' at the bottom and the 'latest' at the top. Here is my

**index.html**

```
{% extends 'layouts/base.html' %}
{% block title %}
Homepage - {{ block.super }}
{% endblock title %}
{% block content %}
<center>
{% for blog in blogs %}
<h2><a href="{% url 'blog_detail' slug=blog.slug %}">
{{ blog.name }}
</a></h2>
<p>{{ blog.description }}</p>
{% endfor %}
</center>
{% endblock content %}
```

**models.py**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone


class blog(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField()
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    date_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name



def get_image_path(instance, filename):
    return '/'.join(['blog_images', instance.bupimg.slug, filename])

class Upload(models.Model):
    bupimg = models.ForeignKey(blog, related_name="uploads")
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_image_path)
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from blogging.models import *


def index(request):
    blogs = blog.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'index.html', {
        'blogs':blogs,
    })

def blog_detail(request, slug):
    article = blog.objects.get(slug=slug)
    uploads = article.uploads.all()
    return render(request, 'blogs/blog_detail.html', {
        'article': article,
        'uploads': uploads,
    })
```

How can I move the blog title 'earliest' to the downside ,'latest' on top side? I need let the latest blog shows on the top.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not sorting the blogs, they come in a random order. Try changing the line

```
blogs = blog.objects.all()
```

to

```
blogs = blog.objects.order_by('-date_time')
```

The minus (`-`) denotes descending sort, ie. from the latest to the oldest.

Comment: I thought it was ordered by the id by default if no Meta.ordering has been defined? I may have misunderstood the docs for [orderby](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#order-by)..

Comment: @Sayse Nope, the SQL generated has no `ORDER BY` clause by default. Where does it say that in the documents?

Comment: I can't remember right now (I'm not at my computer). I didn't necessarily mean ordered at a database level but it would make sense given the ordering shown in the op's screenshot.  I'll try to find something about it next time I'm at a pc

Comment: @Sayse An empty database will usually store the data in the order they are `INSERT`ed; that's why the default order is usually chronological, but it doesn't have to be.

Comment: Sure, thats what I was referring to. I've never seen an instance of when objects weren't output in the order they were inserted but I suppose if it really matters it shouldn't be relied upon. +1 anywho

Comment: @Sayse It is sometimes surprising, but see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7164126/2011147) for a detailed explanation.