# django values_list unexpected behaviour

Tags: mysql, django, django-models, django-queryset

I have a model which has 2 fields

```
class MyModel: 
    name = charField()
    code = charField(unique=True)
```

Thats all. no other fields or meta class, nothing.. it's all here.

and in Mysql table I have 8 entries/rows

```
ID name              code
-------------------------
8  Aborted           ABT
7  Returned          RTC
6  Delivery-Failed   DLF
5  Delivered         DLV
4  Out-for-Delivery  OFD
3  Ready-to-Deliver  RTD
2  Order-Placed      OPD
1  in transit        INT
```

thats means, the very first entry I did was ("in transit", "INT") then OPD..and so on.

so when I use `values_list` on this table it returns

```
MyModel.objects.values_list('code', 'name')

[(u'INT', u'in transit'), (u'OPD', u'Order-Placed'), (u'RTD', u'Ready-to-Deliver'), (u'OFD', u'Out-for-Delivery'), (u'DLV', u'Delivered'), (u'DLF', u'Delivery-Failed'), (u'RTC', u'Returned'), (u'ABT', u'Aborted')]
```

which is in expected order, i mean first entry first and last one last.

now when I do `MyModel.objects.values_list('code')`
it returns

```
[(u'ABT',), (u'DLF',), (u'DLV',), (u'INT',), (u'OFD',), (u'OPD',), (u'RTC',), (u'RTD',)]
```

`State.objects.values_list('code', flat=True)` returns same result as well.

which seems to be random at first but it seems it's alphabetically sorted.

This is not all,
I even tried to pass slicing list in filter

```
MyMode.objects.filter(code__in=['DLF', 'RTC', 'ABT'][1:]).values_list('code', 'name')
```

and it again returned some unordered data
`[(u'ABT', u'Aborted'), (u'RTC', u'Returned')]`

now I want to understand why this is happening. if it's in the code, why django developers did this sorting by default?

PS: I didn't find anything helpful from th doc
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#values-list

the code doesn't say anything too
https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/query.py#L146

PS: I'm using django 1.9.6 and Mysql Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.47

Comment: What version of Django and MySQL are you using? I have tested with Django v1.8.6 and PostgreSQL and did not observe the alphabetical sorting

Comment: `django 1.9.6` and  `mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.47`

Answer (score 1):

The most likely reason for this is the default ordering returned by the database. I can not be more certain than I am only because I do not know if full model description has been posted. As far as I can tell, there's no DJANGO magic involved here. To guarantee the expected ordering, Django relies on the [default ordering](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.ordered) specified by the model's author.

This seems like the [most relevant/related SO QA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7163640/what-is-the-default-order-of-a-list-returned-from-a-django-filter-call) to the current one. Please have a look at the OP's edit and the accepted answer.

**EDIT:**
Okay, it appears [mysql's default order does depend on either insert order or primary key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8746519/sql-what-is-the-default-order-by-of-queries). Databases are free to implement a default order of their own, and it is a good thing because they can choose to give the best performance for those cases. This is precisely the reason why DJANGO models and other ORMs specifically have a way to provide default ordering on models.

AGAIN, to repeat (and this can't be iterated enough!) - quoting from [an answer in this post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/6051/what-is-the-default-order-of-records-for-a-select-statement-in-mysql)

> In the SQL world, order is not an inherent property of a set of data.
>   Thus, you get no guarantees from your RDBMS that your data will come
>   back in a certain order -- or even in a consistent order -- unless you
>   query your data with an ORDER BY clause

Be especially vary of using slicing on top of the queryset if order is not specified, because SQL's `TOP` is applied on the ordered results, and without explicit order to sort RDBMS implementations are free to choose their own and possibly use one at random across versions or [even execution to execution](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5774/why-is-ssms-inserting-new-rows-at-the-top-of-a-table-not-the-bottom/5775#5775) (because it depends on the query plan implementation of the RDBMS in question).