# Django check if querysets are equals

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have this django code

```
q1 = MyModel.objects.all()
q2 = MyModel.objects.all()
```

When I try:

```
print(q1 == q2)
```

I get as a result:

```
False
```

So how can I check if two querysets results in django are equal?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can convert the querysets to lists and check whether they are equal:

```
list(q1) == list(q2)
```

Comment: Ordering isn't guaranteed, so this won't necessarily work - though part of it comes down to "do you consider querysets with the same content but different order equal or not"?

Comment: In your example, you still aren't guaranteed that the reverse ordered queryset will have a different order from the non reversed queryset. The order is not guaranteed before you call reverse() so you have no idea what order is being reversed. Adding an order by would fix that and clear up ambiguity. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7163640/what-is-the-default-order-of-a-list-returned-from-a-django-filter-call#7164126

Comment: The meaning of 'equal' in the question is vague. I assumed that two querysets containing the same items but in different orders are not equal. This is the same as Python lists, where `[1, 2] == [2, 1]` evaluates to `False`. If you want to know whether two querysets 'contain the same items', then you'd need a different approach (e.g. sort the lists). If you don't care about duplicate items, you might want to convert to sets before comparing.

Comment: thank you for your answer, I undertood what you mean, 
but in my case it's the same function that read/write elements, so my queryset will have always the same order,

Comment: Do you think that it is better to test: a) querysets converted to lists, or b) querysets using assertQuerysetEqual?

Comment: @TD1 to compare two querysets, I don't think it matters too much. Note that [`assertQuerySetEqual`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.TransactionTestCase.assertQuerysetEqual) has extra options `transform` and `repr` that can be useful. For [example](https://github.com/django/django/blob/789c47e6de70ca8249aceac83d629c5d38070e45/tests/ordering/tests.py#L31) you can use `transform` to compare a queryset to a list of strings.

Comment: I didn't work for me, I returns false even if I printed it and I saw it looked the same.

Comment: @AnonymousUser if you’re printing the results you might be missing the difference. You could zip the two querysets together and check they are the same, e.g. `for x, y in zip(q1, q2): print(x, y, x==y)`

Answer (score 12):

You can convert it to set, to check if 2 query sets have the same elements, without regard to ordering:

```
set(q1) == set(q2)
```

it will return:

```
True
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
q1.intersection(q2).count() == q1.count() and q1.count() == q2.count()
```

Comment: Could we do this ?
q1.intersection(q2).count() == q1.count() == q2.count()

Comment: It should work to do it like that in python, yeah. I have c habits that's why I wrote it the other way.

Answer (score 0):

Throwing in my two cents for a function that compares two QuerySets for equality *while ignoring sort order*. Note I'm not actually checking whether the QuerySets are empty or not; I'll leave that up to you.

```
def querysets_are_same(qs1, qs2, exclude_fields=[]):
     '''
     Check whether two queryset have the same content, sort order of querysets is ignored.

     Params:
     -------
     qs1 (QuerySet) - first queryset to compare
     qs2 (QuerySet) - second queryset to compare
     exclude_fields (list) - fields to exclude from comparison; primary key field is automatically removed.

     Yield:
     ------
     True if both querysets contain the same data while ignoring sort order; False otherwise
     '''

     # lookup primary key field name
     pk_qs1 = qs1[0]._meta.pk.name
     pk_qs2 = qs2[0]._meta.pk.name

     # update excluded fields
     exclude_fields_qs1 = set(exclude_fields) | set([pk_qs1])
     exclude_fields_qs2 = set(exclude_fields) | set([pk_qs2])

     # convert queryset to list of dicts excluding fields
     list_qs1 = [{k:v for k,v in d.items() if not k in exclude_fields_qs1} for d in qs1.values()]
     list_qs2 = [{k:v for k,v in d.items() if not k in exclude_fields_qs2} for d in qs2.values()]

     # sort lists
     list_qs1_sorted = sorted(sorted(d.items()) for d in list_qs1)
     list_qs2_sorted = sorted(sorted(d.items()) for d in list_qs2)

     return list_qs1_sorted == list_qs2_sorted
```

Answer (score -4):

You can see by .count() or:

```
q1 = Model.objects.all()
q2 = Model.objects.all()
equal = True
for idx, q in q1:
    if q != q2[idx]:
       equal = False
print(equal)
```

Comment: Not that comparing `count()` will only check that the querysets have the same number of items. It won't check whether they are the same items, or whether they are in the same order.