# Order of returned django records changed after upgrading to postgrers12?

Tags: python, django, postgresql

Our Django project has been running on Postgres 10.15 for a while and now we need to upgrade to Postgres12. While running the unit tests, one of them broke. Turns out, the reason for this is that after fetching objects using `xyz.abc_list.all()`, (`abc` references `xyz` with the related name `abc_list`) the order of the returned objects have changed (PS. the model class `abc` does not have any ordering in meta).

I have been trying to go through the [changelog of postgres](https://why-upgrade.depesz.com/show?from=10.15&to=12.3&keywords=) but have not been able to find anything that gives a solid reason for the change in this behavior. AFAIK, the [django does not ensure any ordering if not mentioned..](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7163640/what-is-the-default-order-of-a-list-returned-from-a-django-filter-call)

Can there be proper reasoning established for this change in behavior?

Comment: without order by query result ordering is not deterministic

Comment: You need to add ordering to the query or update the test to not require a consistent ordering.